# Complex Integral of $\frac{1}{z^2-4}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Let $\gamma: [-\pi,\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be given via $\gamma(t) = 3e^{it}$. I am supposed to find $\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z^2-4} dz $

So I am unsure if I am supposed to use a theorem from Complex Analysis or brut force it. (this is my main question really)

I tried to find an anti-derivative for $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2-4}$ Then just plug in my limits but it gets messy,

Then I tried

$\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z^2-4} dz = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1}{(3e^{it}+2)(3e^{it}-2)}dt$ And I get stuck, unfortunately I took the calculus series about a decade ago so my integration is rusty, I am enrolled in a complex analysis course at CSULB. Thank you in advance, just need like a hint really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The poles inside the contour are $2$ and $-2$. The residues at these points are $\frac 1 4$ and $-\frac  1 4$. Hence (by the Residue Theorem) the integral is $2\pi i (\frac 1 4-\frac 1 4)=0$.

Comment: is that the only way/most standard way to do this integral? could you do it by brut force? or is it intended to apply residue theorem. and thanks so much

Comment: @HossienSahebjame Another way is to write $\frac 1{z^{2}-4}$ as $\frac 1 4 (\frac  1 {z-2}-\frac 1 {z+2}$ and show that $\frca  1 {z-2}$ and $\frac 1 {z+2}$ have the same integral using the simple change of variable $z\to -z$).

Comment: ohhhh partial fraction decomposing it!!!! got it thanks!!!